# I need to concatenate and return the 0

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google sheets.

I have formatted column A to number ##.  So cell A1 is 01.  Then I'm concatenating =concatenate(A1, "EFT") and it's returning 1EFT.  How do I get it to return 01EFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=concatenate(text(A1,"00"), "EFT")
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=TEXT(A1; "00")&"EFT"
```

for array:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(A1:A; "00")&"EFT")
```